# This Feature is not supported in the Specified version of QBXML

Tags: vb.net, quickbooks

I am writing a small function to save the Account data into Quick Books sample product,when i try to save it give the error like

```
           **This Feature is not supported in the Specified version of QBXML**
```

when i run the same function with Quick books 2010 (US) it is working .But ,when i try to run with Australian QB2012 i am getting error.

How can i resolve this issue please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward - *the feature you're trying to use, isn't supported by Australian QuickBooks 2012, using the version of qbXML that you requested*.

Since you didn't post your qbXML request or any other details about what version of qbXML you're using, there's not much other help anyone is going to be able to give you.

**Update to reflect your new comments**:

Per your comments:

> i am using QBXML version 6.0

and

> when call this ItemInventoryAssemblyMod.IncomeAccountRef.ListID.SetValue(cmbIncomeAct.SelectedI‌​tem(3).ToString) . then it give the error

If you refer to the documentation:

- http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

You'll notice that it indicates that this tag/node:

```
ItemInventoryAssemblyMod/IncomeAccountRef/ListID
```

Is only supported in qbXML versions *7.0* and higher. You're using *6.0*. Thus, the problem is exactly as indicated by the error message: *the feature you're trying to use isn't supported by the version of qbXML that you requested*.

Either use a higher version of qbXML (if your version of QuickBooks supports it) or you won't be able to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Keith thank you for ur replay , i am using QBXML version 6.0 , QBFC12,QBXMLRP2 12.0 and QBSDKEVENTLib is 1.0 . when call this ItemInventoryAssemblyMod.IncomeAccountRef.ListID.SetValue(cmbIncomeAct.SelectedItem(3).ToString) . then it give the error .